# Why did Richard Coyle leave 'Coupling'?

Tags: character, coupling

In ***Coupling***, [Richard Coyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Coyle) ([Jeff Murdock](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0237123/characters/nm0185404)) left the series before the 4th season. Does anybody know the reason?

I looked at the [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0237123) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28UK_TV_series%29) pages but couldn't find any useful information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Richard Coyle*** himself [said in an interview](http://www.officiallondontheatre.co.uk/news/latest-news/article/item71460/the-big-interview-richard-coyle/) that he was afraid of being typecast:

> ***I was very keen that that character didn’t stick with me.** It’s the kind of character that does.*
>
> *I’m an actor and I want to be an actor when I’m 60. It’s a lifelong process, why cut it off by boxing yourself into a little pigeon hole early on?*

but

> *It was a very difficult decision; incredibly difficult because there was something nice about the fact that I knew, for three years, once a year we all came together for three months and had an almighty laugh.*

The writer/creator of the series, ***Steven Moffat***, [had this to say](http://www.readjunk.com/interviews/steven-moffat-writer-creator-of-coupling/) about *Richard Coyle's* departure:

> *Richard didn’t want to return. Or do a goodbye episode. Or in fact talk to me. Hurtful behaviour, but it’s showbiz, these things happen. Can’t give you any insight, except these wise words, spoken by – er – a wise person: an actor will forgive you for anything but their first success.*

Comment: He went on to star in a short-lived series called Strange, which was a kind of X-Filesish, Supernatural-type mish mash. He later showed up in Prince of Persia: Sands of Time. He also has the key to paradise, but has too many legs.

Comment: Also main character in Going Postal.